# Creating a basic compression algorithm

Tags: java, algorithm, compression

Main Method
: Takes integer array and compresses it into a string using SparseCompression().

```
public class Compress
{
   public static void main(String[] args)
   {
      int[] test = {0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 999};
      String result = SparseCompression(test);

      // expected result: "#7,999," 
      System.out.println(result);
      //need to compress something like(2,0,0,0,54,0,0,2)
      // expected result: "2,#3,54,#2,2"
   }
```

Compression Algorithm: 
So far the array must start with consecutive zeros and then ends at first non-zero. Needs to be able to start with a non-zero and continue on until the end of the array. Something like (4,0,0,0,0,45,65,0,0,0,5).

```
public static String SparseCompression(int[] array)
   {  
      int count = 0;
      int nonZero = 0;
      int after = 0;
      for(int i = 0; i< array.length; i++)
      {
         if(array[i] == 0)
         {
            count++;
         }
         else if(array[i] != 0)
         {
           nonZero = array[i];
         }

      }
      Integer.toString(count);
      String result = "#" + count + ", " + nonZero;
      return result;
      }
   }
```

Comment: What is your question? It looks like this is a homework question and you don't understand what you are being asked to do. Please read up on the site policy for posting questions about homework.

Answer (score 0):

```
public static String SparseCompression(int[] array) {
    if (null == array || array.length == 0) {
        return "";
    }
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
    int count = 0;
    for (int a : array) {
        if (a == 0) {
            count++;
            continue;
        }
        if (count != 0) {
            sb.append("#" + count + ",");
            count = 0;
        }
        sb.append(a + ",");
    }
    if (count != 0) {
        sb.append("#" + count + ",");
    }
    return sb.toString().substring(0, sb.length() - 1);
}
```